# Как сделать callback при выполнении запроса mysql node.js

Tags: node.js

Как дописать функцию что бы она отдавала объект при выполнение запроса? Как к ней дописать coolback Прошу за ранние прощения не силен в этом.

```
function user(val) {
var sss='';
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    database: 'base',
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: ""
});

connection.query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `uid`="+val+"",
    function(err, results) {
        console.log(results); //Тут все пришло!!!
        console.log(err);
        sss =results;
    });
connection.end();
return sss;
}
console.info(user(31)); //Тут пусто!!!
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function user(val) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var sss='';
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        database: 'base',
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: ""
    });

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `uid`="+val+"",
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(results);
        });
    connection.end();
})
}

let user = user(31)
.then(function(user) {
    console.log(user); //Здесь прийдёт
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err); //Здесь будет ошибка в случае чего
})
```